# Is there a word that means "full of spiders"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm just wondering if there exists such a word that means "full of spiders"?

Comment: Yes, it's AAaaaaIIIIIeeeEEEEEEE!!!!!!

Comment: Would the adjective phrase *spider-infested* suit your purposes?

Answer (score 4):

**[spidery](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spidery)**

> *adj.* **3.** full of spiders.